# error when installing lftp

Tags: centos, yum, ftp

I am attempting to install lftp on centos I use the command;

```
yum install lftp
```

this is the error i am getting:

```
Could not retrieve mirrorlist    http://s2plmirror01.prod.sdl2.secureserver.net/vph/2/download/mirrors/cos-5.i386 error was
[Errno 4] IOError: <urlopen error (-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution')>
```

Comment: Paste in the results of `cat /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: nameserver 208.109.188.1
nameserver 208.109.188.2

Comment: Are you using a proxy server for HTTP traffic?

Comment: At a terminal, type `host s2plmirror01.prod.sdl2.secureserver.net`

Comment: connection timed out no server could be reached .... I just used yum the other day not sure why it is doing this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with your DNS servers. `208.109.188.1` and `208.109.188.2` are GoDaddy default DNS servers. At the moment, it appears that `208.109.188.1` is not responding properly. I recommend changing your `resolv.conf` file to use another DNS provider. Perhaps OpenDNS: `208.67.220.220` and `208.67.222.222`

### EDIT 1

Try temporarily disabling iptables to test if it's a firewall rule:

```
/etc/init.d/iptables save
/etc/init.d/iptables stop
```

Test it and then restart the firewall:

```
/etc/init.d/iptables start
```

### Edit 2

It was an iptables rule causing traffic blockage.

Comment: this time it gave me this:
    * atomic: www2.atomicorp.com
    * rpmforge: apt.sw.be
then the same error as before

Comment: could this have to do my my repos

Comment: @user1272737 Try `yum clean all`

Comment: same error now with this after: Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: addons

Comment: @user1272737 Can you ping any internet address by its name? `ping google.com` or `ping bing.com`? What about ip addresses like `ping 8.8.8.8` or `ping 208.67.222.222`? How about `wget http://newark1.linode.com/100MB-newark.bin` (just a 100mb file to test connection speed with)

Comment: wget is not working also ping returned unknown host for google.com. this must be a dns issue ... errors im getting:
    ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

    ping: unknown host google.com

Comment: can you `ping 208.67.222.222`? `traceroute 208.67.222.222`?

Comment: PING 208.67.222.222 (208.67.222.222) 56(84) bytes of data. but it does not return me to the prompt

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3052/discussion-between-wesleydavid-and-user1272737)

Answer (score 1):

Check your DNS server/configuration to see if it can resolve the hostname `s2plmirror01.prod.sdl2.secureserver.net`.